# Bash - how can i pass variable to command and read its output

Tags: bash

In my bash script i want to execute command that will find lines in a file that starts with a keyword which is stored in a variable like this:

```
keyword="key" 
result=(`cat path/to/my/file | grep '^$keyword'`)
```

Comment: Useless use of 'cat' :)  grep $keyword < path/to/my/file

Comment: @jscott: useless use of redirection

Comment: @Dennis: Indeed. I'm not sure the comments parse the ':)' humor markdown correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single quotes inhibit substitution. Use double quotes instead:

```
grep "^$keyword"
```

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me please, i figured it all out as soon as i posted my question:
If has simular issue:

```
keyword="key" 
find_cmd = "cat path/to/my/file | grep '^$keyword'"
result=(`$find_cmd`)
```

Comment: You can't put spaces around the equal sign.